# Correct way of one-hot-encoding class labels for multi-class problem

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, encoding, multiclass-classification

I have a classification problem with multiple classes, let's call them A, B, C and D. My data has the following shape:

```
X=[#samples, #features, 1], y=[#samples,1].
```

To be more specific, the y looks like this:

```
[['A'], ['B'], ['D'], ['A'], ['C'], ...]
```

When I train a Random Forest classifier on these labels, this works fine, however I read multiple times that class labels also need to be one hot encoded.
After the one hot encoding, y is

`[[1,0,0,0], [0,1,0,0], ...]`

and has the shape

`[#samples, 4]`

The problem arises when I try to use this as classifier input. The model predicts every one of the four labels individually, meaning that it is also able to produce an output like [0 0 0 0], which I don't want. `rfc.classes_` returns

```
# [array([0, 1]), array([0, 1]), array([0, 1]), array([0, 1])]
```

How would I tell the model that the labels are one hot encoded instead of multiple labels which shall be predicted independently of each other? Do I need to change my y or do I need to alter some settings of the model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to make one hot encoding when using  random forest in `sklearn`.

What you need is "label encoder", and your Y should looks like

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
y = ["A","B","D","A","C"]
le = LabelEncoder()
le.fit_transform(y)
# array([0, 1, 3, 0, 2], dtype=int64)
```

I tried to modified the sample code sklearn [provided](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html) :

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification

>>> X, y = make_classification(n_samples=1000, n_features=4,
...                            n_informative=2, n_redundant=0,
...                            random_state=0, shuffle=False)
y = np.random.choice(["A","B","C","D"],1000)
print(y.shape)
>>> clf = RandomForestClassifier(max_depth=2, random_state=0)
>>> clf.fit(X, y)
>>> clf.classes_
# array(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], dtype='<U1')
```

Either process the y with label encoding or without, it both worked with `RandomForestClassifier`.

Comment: But then why does the approach with ['A' , 'B', ...] work at all? Does sklearn encode Strings automatically?

Comment: Yes, it deal your y as categorical.

Answer (score 4):

Your original approach, without one-hot encoding, was doing what you wanted.

One-hot encoding is meant for inputs to many models, but outputs for only a few (e.g. training a neural network with cross-entropy loss). So these are only needed for some algorithm implementations, while others can do fine without it.

For output labels, a classifier like RandomForest is just fine with strings and multiple classes.

Answer (score 0):

Here you need not encode the labels , you can keep then as it is whether string or number
as per my knowledge When using neural network you should consider one hot encoding / label encoding
Example is in case of bbc classification data

```
model.predict(sample_data)
```

array(['entertainment'], dtype='<U13')

One hot encoding is mandatory in case of text data in training set :
for example

```
    name         fuel type

    baleno         petrol

    MG hector      electric
```

after on hot encoding

```
  name         fuel type_petrol    fuel_type_electric


 baleno         1                       0


MG hector      0                       1
```